# Mathematically get $n$th bit from integer

Tags: binary

Most programming languages have functions for getting bits but I need to do it on a calculator so I need to understand how to do it mathematically. Basically I need a formula for getting the $n$th bit from and integer, $i$.

So given: $i = 6$ and $n = 3$, I would get $1$ because binary for $6$ is $110$.

How might I manage this?

Comment: Exactly what functions are at your disposal?  Just +, -, *, and /? Do you have a floor function on your calculator?  Sine?  The answer to this question all depends on what functions are available (it can't be done with just +, -, *, and /).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $i$ you want to throw away the bottom $n-1$ bits, so integer divide by $2^{n-1}$.  Then take $\bmod 2$ to get the low order bit.

Answer (score 2):

Another very useful formula for the $k$-th bit of number $b=b_{n}\cdots b_{0}$ is $$b_{k}=\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor.$$ 
This identity can be easily verified by using that, for $b=\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_{i}2^{i}$, we have $\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{i=k}^{n}b_{i}2^{i-k}$.

Comment: Can someone explain what the $-2 \lfloor \frac{b}{2^{k+1}} \rfloor$ does

Comment: @NeelSandell, note that $\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^k}\right\rfloor$ is equivalent to `b>>k`, and $\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor$ to `b>>k+1`, which truncates the last bit after the division by $k$, $2*\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^{k+1}}\right\rfloor$ is equivalent to `b>>k+1<<1`, which is `b>>k&~1`, and `(b>>k)-(b>>k&~1)=b>>k&1`, the $k$th bit.

Answer (score 0):

Most calculators have a way to truncate fractions. So to get bit #3 here are the steps

1. Divide $i$ by $2^{n}$ and truncate the fractional part
2. Divide the quotient by $2$ and take the remainder, i.e. check if it is odd or even

Example: Find the bit #5 of $111$.

$$2^5=32$$
So
$$
111/32=3.46875
$$
The truncated value is $3$. Now, $3$ divided by $2$ leaves $1$ as remainder (odd number). So bit #5 is $1$.

Repeat for bit #4.
$$ 2^4=16$$. So
$$
111/16 = 6.9375
$$ 
Truncated answer is $6$ which is even. So bit #4 is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use mod then its easy: `((value - (value mod (2^n))) / (2^n)) mod 2`

Otherwise bit`0` is `(1+(-1^(value+1)))/2` - applicable for any integer value or any function that returns integer value. Attempts to  emulate mod of a function may lead to result which also contain mod operation.

To get n-th bit,

first lets shift value/function: shift right is `(valuable - bit 0) / 2` - apply n times.

next get bit`0` as described.