# Efficient Meromorphic Approximation For Getting the ith Bit of a Number

Tags: approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, meromorphic-functions

Thanks to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2302476/811299), I know that to get the $i$th bit of a number $n$, you can do $$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{i+1}}\right\rfloor$$
However, I need this formula to be meromorphic (I'm trying to create a function that I could apply the [Argument Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3779139/811299) to). Of course, the floor function isn't meromorphic, so I need an approximation (hopefully with some kind of constant $k$ that I can change to decrease the error). I would also like for it to be efficient (the number of terms are constant or proportional with $\log_2(n)$)

I would make this question just about the floor function, however, if there's some other approximation that uses some other formula to find the $i$th bit, I'm all ears.

Comment: Could you say a little more about your motivation for finding a $w=f(z)$ approximation ? It could help. A priori, it's not evident : you have very different mathematical "worlds" (complex function theory and binary representations) that are not accustomed to invite one another at their respective homes....

Comment: @JeanMarie I added it now. I basically need it so I could apply the Argument Principle to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Consideration* (too long for a comment)

We might think to shift to the *fractional part* $\{ \left\{ x \right\}$
$$
x = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\}\quad \left| {\,0 \le \left\{ x \right\} < 1} \right.
$$
so that
$$
\left\lfloor {{n \over {2^k }}} \right\rfloor  - 2\left\lfloor {{n \over {2^{k + 1} }}} \right\rfloor
  = {n \over {2^k }} - \left\{ {{n \over {2^k }}} \right\} - 2{n \over {2^{k + 1} }} + 2\left\{ {{n \over {2^{k + 1} }}} \right\} = 2\left\{ {{n \over {2^{k + 1} }}} \right\} - \left\{ {{n \over {2^k }}} \right\}
$$

The $\left\{ x \right\}$ in itself is just a [sawtooth wave] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), which can be well approximated by its Fourier series.
However the Fourier approximation gets bad while approaching the peaks, which would be amplified by the difference above .

So this kind of approach needs to be examinated more carefully in consideration of the intended use

Comment: This is good! I'll look into it a bit more. You're right, the peaks really mess it up. But thanks for the start!

Comment: I just saw this question while searching for something, and realized I didn't accept your answer! Well, in any case, an accept is much overdue.

Comment: I appreciate your acceptance and am glad if it was of help to you.