# Mathematical definition of the function to extract a value in an integer by bit selection

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I need the definition of a function $s(v,p,w) = i$ where $v$ is an integer that can be expressed as binary or decimal, $p$ is the position of a bit in $v$, and $w$ is an amount of bit from 1 to $n$. The function return $i$, another integer that corresponds to the $w$'s bits at position $p$ in $v$.

Examples with $v = $ `0b1011` = 11

For $p = 0$ and $w = 1$, $f(11, 0, 1) = 1$

$f(11, p=1, w=1) = 1$

$f(11, p=0, w=2) = 3 = $ `0b11`

$f(11, p=1, w=2) = 1 = $ `0b01`

etc. (sorry for abusive notations).

[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/670597/671827) post partially answer by returning a given bit, but I also need the bit-width ads parameter.

Comment: `(v>>(p+w))` is the number after the range that you want. Then `(v>>(p+w))<<(p+w)` is that padded with zeros on the right. You can subtract `v - (v>>(p+w))<<(p+w)` to remove the first chunk from the left that is not needed. Finally, remove the chunk from the right `(v - (v>>(p+w))<<(p+w))>>p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at [your link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/670597/671827),
I think you can adapt the answer that way:

$$f(b,k,w)=\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2^w\left\lfloor\frac{b}{2^{k+w}}\right\rfloor$$